# How do you aggregate a column on the day before, day of, and day after an event indicated by a flag column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a date column, some self-reports of happiness in another column, and a flag column which indicates a gym day.

I want to get the average happiness scores on the day before, the day of, and the day after a gym session.

If you imagine this table, the averages should return day_before = 1, day_of = 2, and day_after = 3.

[image]

So the set up is like in [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c650/1), although in my actual database the gym flag column is joined in from a separate table.

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`date` datetime, `gym` int, `happiness` int)
;

INSERT INTO test
    (`date`, `gym`, `happiness`)
VALUES
    ('2019-01-06 00:00:00', NULL, 1),
    ('2019-02-06 00:00:00', 1, 2),
    ('2019-03-06 00:00:00', NULL, 3),
    ('2019-04-06 01:00:00', NULL, 1),
    ('2019-05-06 01:00:00', 1, 2),
    ('2019-06-06 01:00:00', NULL, 3),
    ('2019-07-06 01:00:00', NULL, 1),
    ('2019-08-06 01:00:00', 1, 2),
    ('2019-09-06 01:00:00', NULL, 3)
;
```

I tried using a subquery to return when the "gym" column in date - 1 = 1, and also use the results in a case which would have "day of", "day before", and "day after" strings. Then I could simply group by that column. I couldn't get this to work and I'm not even sure if that's something you can do.

Comment: Your dates are not formatted correctly in the fiddle, it should be `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `YYYY-DD-MM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two self-joins.

```
SELECT AVG(before.happiness) AS day_before, AVG(current.happiness) AS day_of, AVG(after.happiness) AS day_after
FROM test AS current
JOIN test AS before ON before.date = DATE_SUB(current.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
JOIN test AS after ON after.date  = DATE_ADD(current.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE current.gym = 1
```

Comment: Great, thanks Barmar! The solution was much simpler than I was making it. I updated the query to match the actual database, in which the event is joined in. Seemed to get it to work, but I'm curious - is this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94025c/14 how you would have done that?